Unable to hibernate, sleep or suspend
I'd like to get hibernate, sleep or suspend to work on my laptop running debian bookworm. I first tried hibernate, but this failed:
█[debian-x1-7th][~][0]$ sudo systemctl start systemd-hibernate.service
Job for systemd-hibernate.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status systemd-hibernate.service" and "journalctl -xeu systemd-hibernate.service" for details.
█[debian-x1-7th][~][1]$ 
█[debian-x1-7th][~][1]$ sudo systemctl status systemd-hibernate.service
× systemd-hibernate.service - System Hibernate
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-hibernate.service; static)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/systemd-hibernate.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2024-06-09 20:03:57 EDT; 9s ago
       Docs: man:systemd-hibernate.service(8)
    Process: 32185 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-sleep hibernate (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 32185 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 12ms

Jun 09 20:03:57 debian-x1-7th systemd[1]: Starting systemd-hibernate.service - System Hibernate...
Jun 09 20:03:57 debian-x1-7th systemd-sleep[32185]: Failed to find location to hibernate to: Function not implemented
Jun 09 20:03:57 debian-x1-7th systemd[1]: systemd-hibernate.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 09 20:03:57 debian-x1-7th systemd[1]: systemd-hibernate.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 09 20:03:57 debian-x1-7th systemd[1]: Failed to start systemd-hibernate.service - System Hibernate.

My system has about twice as much swap as RAM:
█[debian-x1-7th][~][3]$ sudo swapon -s
Filename                                Type            Size            Used            Priority
/dev/nvme0n1p4                          partition       29296636        0               -2
█[debian-x1-7th][~][0]$ free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15Gi       4.9Gi       6.3Gi       469Mi       4.9Gi        10Gi
Swap:           27Gi          0B        27Gi
█[debian-x1-7th][~][0]$ 

I also tried calling systemd-sleep hibernate, but this also failed with the same error:
█[debian-x1-7th][dotfiles][1]$  sudo /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sleep hibernate
Failed to find location to hibernate to: Function not implemented

I read here that

you can't use hibernate feature with a secure boot.

so I would like to at least get suspend or susp. Suspend appears to work
initially, the screen goes blank, but the system comes back from suspension in less than 60 seconds:
█[debian-x1-7th][~][130]$ sudo systemctl start systemd-suspend.service 
█[debian-x1-7th][~][130]$ sudo journalctl -fu systemd-suspend.service
Jun 09 19:29:15 debian-x1-7th systemd[1]: Starting systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend...
Jun 09 19:29:15 debian-x1-7th systemd-sleep[14997]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Jun 09 19:30:01 debian-x1-7th systemd-sleep[14997]: System returned from sleep state.
Jun 09 19:30:01 debian-x1-7th systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jun 09 19:30:01 debian-x1-7th systemd[1]: Finished systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend.
Jun 09 19:31:59 debian-x1-7th systemd[1]: Starting systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend...
Jun 09 19:31:59 debian-x1-7th systemd-sleep[16332]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Jun 09 19:32:46 debian-x1-7th systemd-sleep[16332]: System returned from sleep state.
Jun 09 19:32:46 debian-x1-7th systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jun 09 19:32:46 debian-x1-7th systemd[1]: Finished systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend.

How can I determine what is the reason for the return from sleep state?
I found this thread that suggests disabling items in /proc/acpi/wakeup. I've tried to disable them all but the problem persists.
█[debian-x1-7th][~][130]$ sudo cat /proc/acpi/wakeup | grep enab                                                                       
                                                                                                                                       
GLAN      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1f.6                                                                                            
XHC       S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0                                                                                            
RP09      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0                                                                                            
RP13      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.4                                                                                            
PXSX      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:05:00.0                                                                                            
AWAC      S4    *enabled   platform:ACPI000E:00                                                                                        
SLPB      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0E:00                                                                                         
LID       S4    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00   


█[debian-x1-7th][~][130]$ for DEVICE in $(sudo grep enabled /proc/acpi/wakeup | cut -f1 -d' '); do 
    sudo tee /proc/acpi/wakeup <<< ${DEVICE}; 
done
...

But nothing changes. There is also one entry that apparently cannot be disabled:
grep enabled /proc/acpi/wakeup
PXSX      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:05:00.0

Looking up the bus ID in lspci yields:
sudo lspci | grep 05:00.0
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)

How can I further debug the reason that suspension and sleep are either failing or resuming within 60 seconds?
